# How to add Spring at "add framework support"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I want to add Spring at "add framework support".
but, my Intellij doesn't appear Spring at "add framework support".
I'm using the IntelliJ Ultimate edition.

[image]

my Injellij info

[image]

I've tried "project structure > facets" and tried to delete "spring".
but, there was no Spring in the below image.

[image]

I want to do it.
[image]

Finally, I'm sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Have you enabled the Spring plugin's as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html)?

Comment: yes, I already check it about spring plugIn.

Comment: Please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors/warnings after startup.

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment and sorry for answering late. I checked the idea.log and found the message, "Module intellij.spring.jsf is not enabled because dependency com.intellij.jsf is not available". Did this happen to cause a problem? or Is there another problem?

Comment: Is it possible to attach idea.log after restarting IDE to check your configuration?